Ramification Lemma in a Kummer extension.
I have encountered the following Lemma in a paper:

Lemma:
Let $\ell$ be a prime number and $F$ a field that contains a primitive $\ell$-th root of unity. Let $a\in\mathcal{O}_F$ and $K = F(\sqrt[\ell]{a})$ be a Kummer extension over $F$ of degree $\ell$. Consider the principal ideal
$$(a) = \mathfrak{p}^h\mathfrak{a},\qquad \text{where }(\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{a}) = 1, \text{ and }\mathfrak{p}\text{ is a prime ideal in }F.$$

If $h > 0$ and $(h,\ell) = 1$, then $\mathfrak{p}$ is totally ramified in $K/F$.
If $\mathfrak{p}$ does not divide $\ell$, and $\ell\mid h$, then $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified in $K/F$.


The paper claims that this Lemma is well-known and proven in B. J. Birch, Cyclotomic fields and Kummer extensions in Algebraic Number Theory (Proc. Instructional Conf. Brighton).
I have a copy of that book and the mentioned Lemma is nowhere to be found. I require a reference where the Lemma might be proven, or a proof of the Lemma itself.

I assume that $F$ is a number field here. Let $F_v$ be the completion of $F$ at $\mathfrak{p}$, and let $\pi$ be a uniformizer for this local field, normalized to have valuation $1$.

In $F_v$ we can write $a = \pi^hu$ for a unit $u$. We always have $[F_v(\sqrt[\ell]{a}) : F_v] \leq [F(\sqrt[\ell]{a}) : F] = \ell$, so to show total ramification it suffices to prove that $F_v(\sqrt[\ell]{a})$ has an element of valuation $1/\ell$ (so that this inequality is an equality). But $v(\sqrt[\ell]{a}) = h/\ell$, so using the fact that $(h, \ell) = 1$ shows that some element of the form $\pi^x (\sqrt[\ell]{a})^{y}$ has valuation $1/\ell$, where $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified in $K/F$ if it is unramified in $F_v(\sqrt[\ell]{a})/F_v$. Again write $a = \pi^hu$ in the completion. Since $\ell \mid h$, we have $\sqrt[\ell]{a} = \pi^{h/\ell} \sqrt[\ell]{u}$ with $\pi^{h/\ell}$ an integral power of $\pi$, so it suffices to show that $K_v(\sqrt[\ell]{u}) = K_v(\sqrt[\ell]{a})$ is unramified. The polynomial $X^\ell - u$ has a nonzero root over some finite extension of the residue field of $K_v$. Then $\mathfrak{p} \nmid\ell$ allows us to apply Hensel's lemma to show that $\sqrt[\ell]{u}$ lies in the unramified extension of $K_v$ corresponding to this extension of residue fields.



I am not familiar with some concepts you use in your proof (e.g. completions at a prime ideal and uniformizer for a local field). Could you point me to some reference for me to learn about them? Thank you kindly.
